# R How to Split given Time Periods in interval of 30 days in R

Tags: r, datetime

I have data with Order Id, Start Date & End Date. I have to **split** both the **Start and End dates** into **intervals of 30 days**, and derive two new variables “split start date” and “split end date”.
Example: The below example illustrates how split dates are created when the Start Date is “01/05/2017” and the End Date is “06/07/2017” 
Suppose, an order have start and end dates as below

[see the image for example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jyom6.png)

What is the code for this problem in R ?

Comment: When asking for help, you should include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions. Pictures of data are not particularly helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution which should generalize to multiple order id's. I have created a sample data with two order id's. The basic idea is to calculate the number of intervals between `start_date` and `end_date`. Then we repeat the row for each order id by the number of intervals, and also create a sequence to determine which interval we are in. This is the purpose of creating functions `f` and `g` and the use of `Map`.

The remaining is just vector manipulations where we define `split_start_date` and `split_end_date`. The last statement is to ensure that `split_end_date` does not exceed `end_date`.

```
df <- data.frame(
  order_id = c(1, 2),
  start_date = c(as.Date("2017-05-01"), as.Date("2017-08-01")),
  end_date = c(as.Date("2017-07-06"), as.Date("2017-09-15"))
)
df$diff_days <- as.integer(df$end_date - df$start_date)
df$num_int <- ceiling(df$diff_days / 30)
f <- function(rowindex) {
  rep(rowindex, each = df[rowindex, "num_int"])
}
g <- function(rowindex) {
  1:df[rowindex, "num_int"]
}
rowindex_rep <- unlist(Map(f, 1:nrow(df)))
df2 <- df[rowindex_rep, ]
df2$seq <- unlist(Map(g, 1:nrow(df)))
df3 <- df2
df3$split_start_date <- df3$start_date + (df3$seq - 1) * 30
df3$split_end_date <- df3$split_start_date + 29
df3[which(df3$seq == df3$num_int), ]$split_end_date <-
  df3[which(df3$seq == df3$num_int), ]$end_date
```

Comment: I have fixed a minor typo - (seq - 1) replaced by (df3$seq - 1)

Comment: when i am importing csv file & work your function on it, it is showing many errors. here is the csv file link -  https://files.fm/u/rwhrg7mz

Comment: I have already provided the logic, which appears to work. For the remaining part, you need to learn, understand and solve it yourself. We are not here to solve your homework problems.

Comment: @S.Sur You were supposed to solve this question or take hints. Not copy!!